# VR using Forge Autodesk

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks

Im was working on rendering application which show VR of building model to my user , so user can see model in VR using webVR.

Q.Can I convert model file (NWD file ) to FBX using Forge API? If not then is there any API or way to do so?

Q.Is there anyway I can get emended output or URL which I can easily implement as VR in browser? so user can visit and see it.

Q. can forge will be use for VR means I will pass file it will process and give VRsupported file probably PBX or any support by webVR browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some answers to your questions:

1. The Forge Model Derivative service does not currently support direct NWD->FBX conversion. However, Navisworks itself has an export to FBX option. Here is the 2019 version documentation for that: http://help.autodesk.com/view/NAV/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-853223FE-9DC2-4E8B-9AF4-2D5D1AB38E7F
2. Using our WebVR Extension for the Forge Viewer, you can view a model in WebVR. The extension is conforming to WebVR standard and when compatible hardware is present, the viewer shows the WebVR icon on the toolbar. For example, on a mobile device capable of Google Cardboard you can view it. Or if a browser compatible desktop hardware setup is found, it will work (ie. HTC Vive). To setup this scenario, the model will first need to be translated by Model Derviaitve into SVF (and NWD is suported there) and then the Viewer hosted on your web page (which is the URL you would share with your customers). On our Forge blog, there is a short article about the WebVR extension: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-webvr-support-viewer
3. The process is described in #2 above. We do not support the PBX format. The Forge Viewer is using Three.js to render our SVF format in the browser. And the Viewer WebVR extension provides the connection to the browser and platform ability to render in WebVR on the device.

Overall, before attempting to get WebVR working with the Forge Viewer, if you are not familiar with the Forge web services, I would first go through the tutorial that shows translating a model, and hosting the Viewer in a web page. Then it will be easier for you to implement the WebVR extension. Each API topic in the developer documentation has a step-by-step tutorial (developer.autodesk.com), but an even better way to pull it together in one place, and depending on your choice of programming environments, we have a learning portal here: http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/

hope it helps.